# Start the networking from scratch

Tags: networking

Let us assume I have a computer that for some reasons has had all the networking information, in particular the stuff in /etc, wiped. Furthermore whatever caused the information to be wiped prevents the /etc folder to be modified.

I've booted the computer,  nothing regarding networking has been set up  ( assume the driver for the card is loaded ). Now I need to initilialize and start the network from scratch.

Can some describe the needed steps to set up the gateway, routing etc needed for networking? Or at least point me to a reference which does does.

Comment: "prevents the /etc folder to be modified" - is it a permission error?

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` will set up any interfaces that you need.
`route add` will set up any routing including the gateway.

See the man pages for each on how to use them if you do not already know.

If you want to restore files in /etc and the system won't let you, then you may want to try booting off alternate media such as USB/DVD/network into single-user, mounting your root partition as a separate read-write file system and restoring. This would require access to a similar system's /etc directory if you don't have backups.

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily mount a writeable mountpoint (could be a copy from another machine) over /etc and put your configuration there.

`ifconfig` in combination with route add should work fine.
Only for DNS you would still require `/etc`: under most configurations, applications look up `/etc/resolv.conf` for DNS settings (and if they're to look elsewhere, that would be indicated in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`).